# Typeorm + nestjs, relacion de muchos a muchos e insertar

Tags: javascript, mssql, nestjs, typeorm

Tengo las entidades product, gender y size, produc y gender tienen una relacion de muchos a uno y product y size tienen una relacion de muchos a muchos.

Mi pregunta es por que cuando realizo una inserccion de datos a productos desde postman me sale error si el id de gender no existe, pero si envio id de size que no existen no arroja error y no me inserta nada en product_size pero si me inserta en producto.

**Estas son mis entidades:**

```
@Entity()
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string

  @ManyToOne(() => Gender, gender => gender.product)
  gender: Gender

  @ManyToMany(() => Size, size => size.product)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'product_size',
    joinColumn: { name: 'productId' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'sizeId' }
  })
  sizes: Size[]
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Size {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @ManyToMany(() => Product, product => product.sizes)
  product: Product[]
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Gender {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @OneToMany(() => Product, product => product.gender)
  product: Product[]
}
```

**Y asi inserto los datos:**

```
async create(createProductDto: CreateProductDto) {
    try {
      const {  sizes = [], ...producDetails } = createProductDto

      const product = this.productRespository.create({
        ...producDetails,
        sizes: await this.sizeRespository.findBy({ id: In(sizes) })
        ),
      })

      await this.productRespository.save(product)

      return product
    } catch (error) {
      handleDBExceptions(error, 'ProductsService')
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaro un **vector objSizes: Size[]**, el cual tendra asignado el resultado de la consulta a la bd de los id's de las sizes.

Si el tamaño del vector es igual a 0 significa que ningun size con ese id existe y devuelvo un NotFoundException, con esto evito la creacion de un product cuando no llegan sizes validos o directamente no envian ninguno, en caso contrario asigno objSizes a product.sizes y se guardan el product y la relacion entre products y sizes

```
  async create(createProductDto: CreateProductDto) {
    try {
      const { images = [], sizes = [], tags = [], ...producDetails } = createProductDto

      const objSizes = await this.sizeRespository.findBy({ id: In(sizes) })
      if (objSizes.lenth === 0) throw new NotFoundException(`Sizes with id's ${sizes} not found`)

      const product = this.productRespository.create({
        ...producDetails,
        sizes: objSizes,
        images: images.map(url => this.productImageRespository.create({ url })
        ),
      })

      await this.productRespository.save(product)

      return product
    } catch (error) {
      handleDBExceptions(error, 'ProductsService')
    }
  }
```